# NSArray "out of scope"

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

**.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *m_plistData;
```

**.m**

```
@synthesize m_plistData;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"0",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14", nil];    
    m_plistData = array;
    NSArray *nn = m_plistData;    
    [super viewDidLoad];    
}
```

I use breakpoint and found array is normal,but m_plistData has no values,shows "out of scope",I can't understand why nn can get normal values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array` is a local reference variable. It just lasts until `viewDidLoad` method. Now,

```
m_plistData = array;
```

The above statement doesn't make a deep copy. It is just a shallow copy.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"0",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14", nil];    
    m_plistData = array;
    NSArray *nn = m_plistData;    
    [super viewDidLoad];    
} // Both the array, nn references cease to exist after this point.
  // So having references to it leads to run-time exception if used else where.
```

If your objective is have elements in `m_plistData`, directly do -

```
m_plistData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"0",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14", nil];
```

Comment: Why `NSArray *array` at all required ? Directly assign it to `m_plistData`.

Comment: I have tried like this:m_plistData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"0",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14", nil]; 
    [m_plistData retain]; but it's still "out of scope",i can't get the values

Comment: @Gaojian - What is out of scope? Where are you trying to access the reference `m_plistData` ? It can be used only it's interface scope.

Comment: ok,i just want to declare an array to store my data,and show these datas in my tableview.so how i can assign my data to an array.

Comment: @Gaojian - What I said should work. What is the exact error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
m_plistData = [array copy];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this as you have a `NSAarray`:

```
if(array)
{
  m_plistData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
}
```